# c++ проблема со статическим классом

Tags: c++, классы

Здравствуйте, есть классы с заголовками.

Класс LOGVOTING

```
#pragma once
#include "Fraction.h"
#include "vector"
using namespace std;
static class LogVoting
{
public:
    /*LogVoting(){
        RegisteredDeputy = new vector<Deputy*>;
        RegisteredFraction = new vector<Fraction*>;
        Logs::PutMessage("Создан журнал голосования");
    };*/
    static  vector<Deputy*> RegisteredDeputy;
    static      vector<Fraction*> RegisteredFraction;
};
```

DEPUTY

```
#pragma once
#include "GovernmentEmployee.h"
#include "Human.h"

class Deputy : public GovernmentEmployee, public Human
{
public:
    Deputy(){ NumberOfPlaces = 0; };
    Deputy(unsigned number );
    Deputy(unsigned number, bool immunity, int age, string name, string surname, PeopleGender gender);
    virtual ~Deputy();

    unsigned get_Number();
    bool set_Number(int number);

protected:
    unsigned NumberOfPlaces;

};
```

FRACTION

```
#pragma once
#include "Deputy.h"
#include "vector"

class Fraction
{
public:
    Fraction();
    Fraction(string name, Deputy *leader,unsigned maxCountMembers);
    ~Fraction();

    bool set_Name(string name);
    string get_Name();
    unsigned get_MaxCountMembers();

    Deputy* get_Leader();
    bool set_Leader(Deputy *deputy);

    bool AddToDeputsList(Deputy* deputy);
    void DeleteDeputsFromList(Deputy * deputy);
protected:
    unsigned MaxCountMembers;
    string Name;
    vector<Deputy*> DeputyList;
    Deputy  *Leader;
};
```

И при таком обращении LogVoting::RegisteredDeputy выдается куча ошибок вида:

```
Ошибка  12  error LNK2020: эхЁрчЁх°хээр  ыхъёхьр (0A000438) "public: static class std::vector<class Deputy *,class std::allocator<class Deputy *> > LogVoting::RegisteredDeputy" (?RegisteredDeputy@LogVoting@@2V?$vector@PAVDeputy@@V?$allocator@PAVDeputy@@@std@@@std@@A)
```

Comment: Поработать за вас переводчиком?  "эхЁрчЁх°хээр  ыхъёхьр" => "неразрешенна  лексема"

Comment: Так вот на что уходят наши налоги!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#pragma once // Это не по стандарту, но большинство популярных
             // компиляторов поддерживают.

#include "Fraction.h" 
#include <vector> // Так лучше! 
// Если используются кавычки, происходит поиск файла сначала в папке 
// проекта. Если угловые скобки - то в стандартных заголовках. Обычно 
// хочется все же стандартный заголовок.

// using namespace std; // Этого в заголовочном файле быть не должно!
// Иначе весь std будет доступен во всех файлах, куда Вы включите 
// LogVoting.h. Обычно это не то, что Вы хотите. Даже если используете 
// в своем проекте, никогда не делайте так на работе! А лучше приучать 
// себя сразу так не делать. 

class LogVoting // В нормальном C++ static здесь быть не должно.
{
public:
    static std::vector<Deputy*> RegisteredDeputy;
    static std::vector<Fraction*> RegisteredFraction;
};

// Инициализируем! Лучше вынести в .cpp, так как иначе будет 
// проблема, указанная в комментарии. При включении этого   
// заголовочного файла в разные .cpp файлы каждый cpp будет 
// содержать свое собственное определение переменной, на что и 
// будет ругаться линкер.
std::vector<Deputy*> LogVoting::RegisteredDeputy;
std::vector<Fraction*> LogVoting::RegisteredFraction;
```

Comment: Ошибка Ошибка 10 error LNK2005: "public: static class std::vector<class Fraction *,class std::allocator<class Fraction *> > LogVoting::RegisteredFraction" (?RegisteredFraction@LogVoting@@2V?$vector@PAVFraction@@V?$allocator@PAVFraction@@@std@@@std@@A) єцх юяЁхфхыхэ т DeputyReg.obj

Comment: В cpp-файле это напишите.

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Спасибо. Не вспомнил про это сразу, давно не сталкивался.

Answer (score 4):

Нужна инициализация static-членов.

Answer (score 4):

Статические члено-переменные нужно объявлять не только внутри класса, но ещё и дублировать снаружи.

```
vector<Deputy*> LogVoting::RegisteredDeputy;
vector<Fraction*> LogVoting::RegisteredFraction;
```